# Princípio da Inversão de Dependência SOLID

Tags: php, solid

Tenho uma classe Funcionário dessa forma:

```
class Funcionario 
{

    public function calcularSalario($cargo, $dpto, $totalHorasExtras, $bonificacao)
    {
        if(strcmp($dpto, "ti") == 0) {
            if(strcmp($cargo, "fullstack1")) {
                $salario = 3000;
                $horaExtra = 15;
                return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra); 
            }

            if(strcmp($cargo, "dev_junior")) {
                $salario = 4000;
                $horaExtra = 20;
                return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra); 
            }

            if(strcmp($cargo, "dev_pleno")) {
                $salario = 5000;
                $horaExtra = 25;
                return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra); 
            }

            if(strcmp($cargo, "analista")) {
                $salario = 6000;
                $horaExtra = 30;
                return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra); 
            }
        }

        if(strcmp($dpto, "comercial") == 0) {
            if(strcmp($cargo, "vendedor_junior")) {
                $salario = 3000;
                $horaExtra = 15;
                return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra) + $bonificaca; 
            }

            if(strcmp($cargo, "vendedor_pleno")) {
                $salario = 4000;
                $horaExtra = 20;
                return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra) + $bonificaca; 
            }

            if(strcmp($cargo, "vendedor_senior")) {
                $salario = 5000;
                $horaExtra = 25;
                return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra) + $bonificaca; 
            }

            if(strcmp($cargo, "gestor")) {
                $salario = 6000;
                $horaExtra = 30;
                return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra) + $bonificaca; 
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Gostaria de saber como uso o principio de inversão de dependência nesse caso já que para cada departamento o cargo calcula seu salário de forma diferente.

```
class Funcionario{
    private $departamento;
    private $cargo;

    public function __construct(Departamento $departamento){
        $this->departamento = $departamento;
    }

    public function calcularSalarioSemBonificacao(Remuneravel $cargo, $totalHorasExtras){
        $this->$cargo = $cargo;
        $this->cargo->calcularSalario($totalHorasExtras);
    }
    public function calcularSalarioComBonificacao(Bonificavel $cargo, $totalHorasExtras, $bonificacao){   
        $this->$cargo = $cargo;
        $this->cargo->calcularSalarioComBonificacao($totalHorasExtras, $bonificacao);
    }
}

class Departamento{
    private String $nome;
    public function setNome(String $nome):void{
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }
}

interface Remuneravel{
    public function calcularSalario($totalHorasExtras);
}

interface Bonificavel{
    public function calcularSalarioComBonificacao($totalHorasExtras, $bonificacao);
}

class FullstackJunior implements Remuneravel{
    public function calcularSalario($totalHorasExtras){
        $salario = 3000;
        $horaExtra = 15;
        return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra); 
    }
}

class VendedorJunior implements Bonificavel{
    public function calcularSalarioComBonificacao($totalHorasExtras, $bonificacao){
        $salario = 3000;
        $horaExtra = 15;
        return $salario + ($totalHorasExtras * $horaExtra) + $bonificacao; 
    }
}

$TI = new Departamento();
$TI->setNome("TI");
$FullstackJunior = new FullstackJunior();
$Joao = new Funcionario($TI);
$Joao->calcularSalarioSemBonificacao($FullstackJunior, 10);


$COMERCIAL = new Departamento();
$COMERCIAL->setNome("COMERCIAL");
$VendedorJunior = new VendedorJunior();
$Jose = new Funcionario($TI);
$Jose->calcularSalarioSemBonificacao($VendedorJunior, 10, 30);
```

Answer (score 2):

- Jogo dos sete erros. Tem duas classes `Funcionario`.
- `FullstackJunior` não deveria ser uma classe, nem `VendedorJunior`. Um desenvolvedor Full-Stack Júnior é um cargo temporário, que muda com o tempo. Não deveria haver uma classe para isso. Para `Funcionario` sim, com campos `Cargo` e `Departamento`. Talvez também `Nível`.
- Já-já falo desse monte de `if`s.
- Objetos devem saber (*getters*) ou fazer coisas. `Funcionario` calcula (sabe) seu próprio salário. A regra deve levar em conta o cargo e o departamento. Se *"para cada departamento o cargo calcula seu salário de forma diferente"*, então significa que a um departamento está vinculado um certo conjunto de cargos. Um funcionário então deve possuir um cargo, e "por tabela", isto é, por consequência, deve saber qual é o seu departamento, buscando a partir do seu cargo a informação de a qual departamento esse cargo pertence.
- Reparou também que a sua classe `Funcionario` não usa nenhum campo dela mesma para calcular o salário, além de cargo e departamento? Sinal que essas regras de cálculo não pertencem a essa classe (uma regra deve ficar onde estão, isto é, na classe em que estão, os campos que ela necessita manipular). Elas devem ficar em departamento ou em cargo, ou ainda distribuídas um pouco em cada uma dessas duas classes. Na verdade pela sua modelagem original o cargo não parece ser levado em conta e sim o nível.
- Na verdade pode-se intuir que o nível é um pouco subjetivo, cada departamento tem os seus (um departamento possui N "níveis de cargo" daquele departamento, certamente ordenados). Ou talvez sejam vinculados a um cargo de um departamento, isso não parece claro. No primeiro caso, a partir do nível se sabe o salário-base daquele departamento.  Isso supondo que todos os níveis tenham um salário-base; isso pode não ser verdade, aí a modelagem seria outra. Note que um júnior de um departamento não é a mesma coisa (não tem necessariamente o mesmo salário) de um júnior de outro departamento.
- Esse negócio de testar o valor de strings cargo e departamento não tem nada de orientado a objetos. Você vai ver que vai virar tudo instanciação dinâmica e eventualmente polimorfismo. Vai ficar mais dinâmico, para acrescentar um nível novo você só pegar a instância de departamento e acrescenta na sua coleção de níveis de cargo uma instância nova da classe NivelDeCargo inicializando com um salário-base específico para aquele nível daquele departamento, e tudo passa a funcionar magicamente. Também não viola o princípio *Aberto-Fechado*.
- Ah sim, respondendo à sua pergunta. A inversão de dependência. Não sei se usei esse princípio nesse raciocínio que construí, talvez sim, talvez não. O princípio diz que se deve depender de abstrações e não de concretudes. Acho que o que precisava ser abstraído foi, como por exemplo a abstração NivelDeCargo e o pertencimento de suas instâncias a um Departamento.
- Nem entrei no mérito das interfaces, por exemplo, `Bonificavel` seria algo exclusivo do departamento de vendas? Não acho que precise declarar uma interface, é questão de customizar de alguma outra forma que não me ocorre agora (acho que um campo da instância de Departamento de vendas), mas tenha em mente os princípios que citei acima.
- Vale pesquisar sobre o princípio *Tell, Don't Ask* e ter em mente que em objetos costumam ficar juntos estado e operações que manipulam esse estado. Isso ajuda a definir as abstrações (classes)-chaves, e qual campo pertence a qual classe. A meu ver ajuda a aplicar o princípio da inversão de dependência.
- E só para deixar claro, quando falo que uma classe tem outra classe ou é vinculada a outra classe estou falando de composição (*HAS-A*, uma classe ter um campo do mesmo tipo ou coleção de um tipo que outra classe). Talvez bidirecional, talvez não. Herança (*IS-A*) a princípio não precisei usar. Talvez o departamento de vendas se torne uma instância de classe à parte, por exemplo uma instância de `DepartamentoBonificavel`, subclasse de `Departamento`, passível de receber no construtor um campo `bonificação` e usar num cálculo (método) que sobrescreve o cálculo original da classe `Departamento`, mas sei lá. A se pensar melhor. Esse raciocínio também sugere um `DepartamentoRemuneravel`. A meu ver essas duas heranças ajudam fazendo o cálculo de Cargo depender de um `Departamento` que é uma abstração e não uma concretude, é dinâmico, e vem por um parâmetro externo (provavelmente passado via construtor).
- Não vou transformar isso em código, divirta-se.